# inserting variables in sql statement

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the right syntax to insert the variables from my form in to the database table.

here is my form...

```
<form name="texcom_daily" method="POST" action="actions/siteSubmit.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" name="id" />
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['first'] ?>" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['last']?>" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?>" maxlength="80" size="40">
 </td>

</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $_POST['telephone']?>" maxlength="40" size="40">

 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="truck_number">Truck Number *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="truck_number" value="<?php echo $_POST['truck_number']?>" maxlength="40" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="truck_milage">Truck Mileage *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="truck_mileage" value="<?php echo $_POST['truck_mileage'] ?>" maxlength="40" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="carrier">Carrier *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="carrier" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['carrier']?>" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="site_number">Site Number *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="site_number" value="<?php echo $_POST['site_number']?>" maxlength="40" size="40">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>
 </td>
  <td valign="top">
 <INPUT type="text" name="lat" ID="lat" value="<?php echo $_POST['lat']?>" maxlength="40" size="40">
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
 </td>
  <td valign="top">
 <input type="text" name="longitude" ID="longitude" value="<?php echo $_POST['longitude']?>" maxlength="40" size="40">
 </td>
 </tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="6"><?php echo $_POST['comments']?></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="job_completion">Job Completion *</label>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align">
  <?php $job_completion = isset($_POST['job_completion']) ? $_POST['job_completion'] : ''; ?> 
<input type="radio" name="job_completion" value="Yes" <?php echo $job_completion === 'Yes' ? "checked='checked'" : ''?> > Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="job_completion" value="No" <?php echo $job_completion === 'No' ? "checked='checked'" : ''?>> No
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

here is the sql statements. the first one works but the sql2 is not entering data into the database.

```
      $sql = "INSERT INTO documents (id, userid, description, name, date) VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['id']}, '{$description}' ,'{$filename}', NOW())"; 
     $success = mysql_query($sql);  


     $sql2 = "INSERT INTO sitesubmit (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, carrier, site_number, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) 
   VALUES  ( '$_POST[first]', '$_POST['last']', '$_POST['email']', '$_POST['telephone']', '$_POST['truck_number']', '$_POST['truck_mileage']', '$_POST['carrier']', '$_POST['site_number']', '$_POST['lat']', '$_POST['longitude']', '$_POST['comments']', '$_POST['job_completion']')";
     $success2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: You don't escape user input which makes you wide open for attack. It also can cause your query to fail if certain data is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
You should always escape values using **mysql_real_escape_string** before submitting values to a database.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO sitesubmit (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, carrier, site_number, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) VALUES  ( '" . $_POST['first'] . "', '" . $_POST['last'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['telephone']. "', '" . $_POST['truck_number'] . "', '" . $_POST['truck_mileage'] . "', '" . $_POST['carrier'] . "', '" . $_POST['site_number'] . "', '" . $_POST['lat'] . "', '" . $_POST['longitude'] . "', '" . $_POST['comments'] . "', '" . $_POST['job_completion'] . "')";
```

Comment: thank you but nothing gets entered to the database... neither statement.

Comment: did you look at the form? I am wondering if I am calling these variables correctly... Would you mind looking and making sure?

Comment: @NichoDiaz

Firstly, you aren't starting the session anywhere. You shouldn't be using '$_SESSION' if you haven't started the session anywhere.

Secondly, there's no need for the value field in the input tags.
Fix these two things and it should work.
If it still doesn't works, please run this and post the output in your question.
var_dump($sql2);
var_dump($success2);

Comment: The session has started just not where I should you. This is simply a form only accessible to people who are logged in. And your looking at the php when they click submit

Comment: @NichoDiaz
Alright, so I guess your script works now ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here: '$_POST[first]' And I would prefer to concatenate the variables instead. Bothersome, but secure way. Try this instead:

"INSERT INTO sitesubmit (first_name, last_name, email, telephone, truck_number, truck_mileage, carrier, site_number, lat, longitude, comments, job_completion) 
   VALUES  ('" . $_POST['first'] . "', '" . $_POST['last'] "', '" ... etc